Postgres count with different condition and different aggregate
I have two queries counting and grouping on different columns:
Get the count of items owned to each user:
SELECT
  user_id,
  COUNT(id)
FROM items
WHERE user_id IN (?)
GROUP BY user_id

Get the count of items created by each user:
SELECT
  created_by_user_id,
  COUNT(id)
FROM items
WHERE created_by_user_id IN (?)
GROUP BY created_by_user_id

There's nothing too complex going on in these, and I'm trying to see if there are ways to get the same results with a single query.
From what I've read, it might be possible to get it to work using FILTER (it is incomplete as I'm still trying to figure it out):
SELECT
  user_id,
  COUNT(id) FILTER (WHERE user_id = ???) AS "Owned",
  COUNT(id) FILTER (WHERE created_by_agent_id = ???) AS "Created"
FROM items

But since my queries GROUP BY on a different row, I'm unsure this approch would fit my use case.
Am I on the right track with FILTER or is there something I've missed?

The aggregations of the 2 queries are different.  Maybe add some sample data.

What were the results when you tried it?

If you do a left join on itself, you can do it in the same query
Schema (PostgreSQL v10)
CREATE TABLE Items (
     "id" int,
     "created_by_user_id" int,
     "user_id" int
  );
  
INSERT INTO Items ("id", "created_by_user_id", "user_id")
VALUES (1, 1, 2)
        , (2, 2, 1)
        , (3, 3, 2)
        , (4, 1, 3)
        , (5, 2, 5)
        , (6, 3, 2)


Query #1
SELECT *
    FROM items first
    LEFT JOIN items second ON first.user_id = second.created_by_user_id
    WHERE first.user_id = 2;




id
created_by_user_id
user_id
id
created_by_user_id
user_id




1
1
2
2
2
1


1
1
2
5
2
5


3
3
2
2
2
1


3
3
2
5
2
5


6
3
2
2
2
1


6
3
2
5
2
5




View on DB Fiddle
Now, what you want is the number of distinct first.id (owned) and number of distinct second.id (created) grouped by user_id.
Query #2
SELECT first.user_id,
    COUNT (DISTINCT first.id) as "owned",
    COUNT (DISTINCT second.id) as "created"
FROM items first
LEFT JOIN items second ON first.user_id = second.created_by_user_id
GROUP BY first.user_id
HAVING first.user_id = 5;




user_id
owned
created




5
1
0




View on DB Fiddle
Update the HAVING to what your specific filter is.
